# How do i use output parameters / pointers correctly with NativeBoost / NBOpenGL?

Tags: opengl, smalltalk, pharo

i am trying to call an OpenGL function through the NBOpenGL wrapper from pharo. The  smalltalk method wrapping this OpenGL function

```
void glGetShaderiv ( GLuint shader , GLenum pname , long* params )
```

has the signature

```
getShaderiv_shader:pname:params
```

So the params: parameter must be a long pointer obviously. Thats why i tried to create one with

```
NativeBoost allocate:
```

but actually, when i call getShaderiv_shader i keep getting

```
Error during FFI call : nil
```

all the time.

What am i doing wrong ??

That parameter is supposed to be an output parameter as well.

I attach the complete code of my method here.

aShader is an int and the GL_ constants are ints too.

```
report:aShader

| len status statusPtr lenPtr logPtr |
len := GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH.
status:= GL_COMPILE_STATUS.
statusPtr := NativeBoost allocate: (NBExternalType sizeOf: 'long'). 
statusPtr nbUInt64AtOffset: 0 put: 0.
gl getShaderiv_shader: aShader pname: status name params: statusPtr.

(statusPtr value == GL_FALSE) ifTrue: [ 
    lenPtr := NativeBoost allocate: (NBExternalType sizeOf: 'int').
    gl getShaderiv_shader: aShader pname: len  params: lenPtr.

    logPtr := NativeBoost allocate: (NBExternalType sizeOf: 'char') * (lenPtr+1). 
    gl getShaderInfoLog_shader: aShader bufSize:lenPtr length: 0 infoLog: logPtr.
].

Transcript show: logPtr.
statusPtr free.
lenPtr free.
logPtr free.
```

I am using Pharo 3.0 under Windows 7, 64 bits. I also installed NBOpenGL in its 2.0 configuration from smalltalkhub.

Comment: I couldn't help but ask if you really need to *allocate* for every integer you use in this funny language?

Comment: I usually get a `nil` return value when the function signature is wrong. Try messing around with the argument types (it might be one of the other arguments that's actually giving you trouble).

Comment: Instead of changing title, you can answer your question yourself.

Comment: Bartek no you dont need to allocate anything in smalltalk. Its a dynamic typed language with GC and in case of pharo a JIT VM. The one doing the allocation is Nativeboost which is a FFI for C libraries and inline Assembler.

Comment: @scorpoan81 - Bartek means answer the question by creating an answer not editing the question - It is OK to answer your own questions